# How to properly get RecyclerView Adapter from Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment that displays a list using my class `ListRecyclerViewAdapter` that extends `RecyclerView.Adapter`:

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        adapter = new ListRecyclerViewAdapter(context, itemsToDisplay);
        ...
    }

    public ListRecyclerViewAdapter getListAdapter() {
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

When I try to get the Adapter from an Activity that has the above Fragment, I get `null`:

```
public class DataActivity extends FragmentActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    listFragment = new ListFragment(itemsToDisplay);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_list_container, listFragment).commit();
    ListRecyclerViewAdapter wantedAdapter = listFragment.getAdapter();
 }

}
```

Why is that? It looks to me like the Fragment's method `onCreateView()` was not called at the point when I call `listFragment.getAdapter()`.

Comment: upload error log in your question to take a look

Comment: im not sure but try to fragmentTransaction.add insited of fragmentTransaction.replace in order to prevent the recreate calling

Comment: create interface and after set adapter on ur fragment then call to ur interface which call in u activity (return adapter)... that's it

Comment: check my answer. i think it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Fragment is not created when you are trying to call the method.So check is the fragment is attached before accessing the adapter.

```
public ListRecyclerViewAdapter getListAdapter() {
    if(this.isAdded() && adapter!=null){
        return adapter;
    }
 return null;   
}
```

Also load the fragment in oncreate of activity and call the adpter reference method in onresume

```
public class DataActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            listFragment = new ListFragment(itemsToDisplay);
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_list_container, listFragment).commit();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            ListRecyclerViewAdapter wantedAdapter = listFragment.getAdapter();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as it created, it called listfragment adapter. so, the UI creation will take some time , but the flow flowed to that line. so it return null. you can acheive this in following way.

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {
LoadAdapter loadAdapter;
private ListRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    adapter = new ListRecyclerViewAdapter(context, itemsToDisplay);
    ...
}

public ListRecyclerViewAdapter getListAdapter() {
    return adapter;
}
interface LoadAdapter {
public void onAdapterLoaded();
}
 public void setOnAdapterLoad(LoadAdapter loadAdapter){
  this.loadAdapter = loadAdapter;
 }
 @Override
 public void onResume(){
    loadAdapter.onAdapterLoaded();
 }

}
```

Now the activity code as follows:

```
public class DataActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  listFragment = new ListFragment(itemsToDisplay);
  listFragment.setOnAdapterLoad(new LoadAdapter(){
   @Override
    public void onAdapterLoaded(){
        ListRecyclerViewAdapter wantedAdapter = listFragment.getAdapter();
    }
  });
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_list_container, listFragment).commit();

}

}
```

Hope this helps.